# Booleans with MongoDB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

How can I post a boolean value (true/false or 0/1) to a MongoDB database. 
When I push a button, I want to save that data to the MongoDB database.
I have a model with one simple bool:

```
public class DynamicFormModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "BooleanOne")]
        public bool BooleanOne { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have made a Strong view with this model.
When I save the boolean, I want to display this boolean in another page, the index.

How can I achive this. I guess I have to make a HttpPost in my controller?

( I already have a connection to a MongoDB database )

Now I can post this boolean in a MongoDB database:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Settings(DynamicFormModel dynamicFormModel)
        {
            Setting setting = dynamicFormModel.ConvertToDomain();
            InvoiceContext.Settings.Insert(setting);
            Response.Redirect("./", true);
            return View(dynamicFormModel);
        }
```

and show:

```
public ActionResult SettingTabel()
        {
            List<Setting> settingsInDb = InvoiceContext.Settings.FindAll().ToList();
            return View(settingsInDb.ConvertAllToViewModels());
        }
```

But now I keep creating new records, but I want ONE record, and keep editing this record instead of creating a new one.

I also want to check if a boolean is true or false in the other page (index), Like display a alert or something.

Comment: Seems like you have multiple questions here. 1. `How do I save a model to the database?` and 2. `How do I display a Boolean property from a model in my view?` Is that correct? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @mason I have edited my question. I am able to save a model in a database and display this data in a list. But I want only one record, and keep editing that one. I also want to display an alert or something with the value of this boolean in it.